# Как в Xamarin.Forms правильно организовать mvvm с WebView?

Tags: c#, mvvm, webview, xamarin.forms

При нажатии на кнопку должен открываться определенный документ HTML хранимый в ресурсах (таких html сотни). Так же должен быть поиск по названию и описанию этих html.
И это все провернуть через mvvm. Т.е. 1.(Model) модель документа, 2. (View) отображение html через WebView, 3. В ViewModel сделать список всех документов.
Однако я слабо понимаю как это сделать.

1. как на на нажатие кнопки открывать в новой странице определенный документ и при этом я мог устроить поиск всех документов и при этом все было устроено через mvvm?
2. как правильно устроить привязку в webview

   View:

   ```
    `<WebView  Source="{Binding webSource}">
     </WebView>`
   ```

   `BindingContext = new WebPageViewModel();`

ViewModel:

```
`public WebViewSource urlSource1 { get; set; }
    public WebPageViewModel()
    {
        UrlWebViewSource urlSource = new UrlWebViewSource();
        urlSource.Url = Path.Combine(DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get(), "sist.html");
        urlSource1 = urlSource;
    }`
```

Comment: `Binding webSource` `public WebViewSource urlSource1` - свойства одинаково должны называться. И если хотите, чтобы UI узнавал об изменениях в вьюмодели, вам нужно вызывать событие `PropertyChanged` передавая в `PropertyChangedEventArgs` название свойства, котрое изменилось. В WPF за это отвечает реализация интерфейса `INotifyPropertyChanged`, от него надо унаследоваться, а вот что там в Xamarin, я точно не припомню, вроде то же самое.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я это уже заметил и поменял, только все равно не проходит привязка

Comment: `...документ HTML хранимый в ресурсах...` что прямо в проект добавлены странички и компилируются как ресуры?

Comment: Ну да, куча страниц, которые лежат в самом проекте

Comment: _только все равно не проходит привязка_ - `DataContext` страницы должен указывать на вашу вьюмодель.